# CodeIgneitor Query Builder Class to select data on multiple condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to use following conditions in my code but only condition 01 and 03 working. Can anyone help me please? My code is:

```
public function errorTime(){

    $fromDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['FromDate']));
    $toDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['ToDate']));
    $this->db->select('*');
```

> Condition 01

```
    $where = "(TimeStatus='Yes' AND CheckIn='00:00:00' OR TimeStatus='Yes' AND CheckOut='00:00:00')";
    $this->db->where($where);
```

> Condition # 02

```
    $this->db->where('TotalTime <', 0);
```

> condition # 03

```
    $this->db->where('Date >=', $fromDate);
    $this->db->where('Date <=', $toDate);

    $this->db->from('tb_time');
    $query=$this->db->get();

    return $query->num_rows();

}
```

Note: TotalTime -> Data Type : Float

Comment: what type of data in `TotalTime` column ?

Comment: @RahulSharma float

Comment: try it \`TotalTime\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure out the solution as:

```
public function errorTime(){

    $fromDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['FromDate']));
    $toDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['ToDate']));
    $this->db->select('*');
    $where = "(TimeStatus='Yes' AND CheckIn='00:00:00' OR TimeStatus='Yes' AND CheckOut='00:00:00' OR CheckOut <= CheckIn)";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->where('Date >=', $fromDate);
    $this->db->where('Date <=', $toDate);
    $this->db->from('tb_time');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $num_rows=$query->num_rows();
}
```